# Spark daily ETL job - how to determine records to load for a particular run?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, etl, delta-lake

I'm writing a simple Spark job to load daily snapshots from a SQL table and dump the results into a delta table (S3).

What is the established pattern to determine what records need to be loaded on a particular run? Do we query the delta lake for the latest record migrated and pick up where we left off? Are there other patterns to store this state?

Comment: do you receive full dumps or only diffs with previous day?

Comment: I only have access the a production mirror which is kept im sync with the real prod db in near real time

Comment: Ah, you're loading directly from database, not from the dumps of database?

Comment: That's correct, directly from thr db